# multiple events, one function in jQuery.on handler

Tags: jquery, html, placeholder, jquery-on

All the examples I've found to emulate HTML5 placeholder for non-supporting browsers trigger on **focus**, which is **NOT** how it works in supporting browsers (*and kinda sucks*). It would be better (IMHO) to trigger on('**keypress**'), but that doesn't accommodate for paste operations, so I'd like to trigger on the combination of (either or) keypress and/or paste events.

```
jQuery(input).on('keypress', function()
{/*works*/}

jQuery(input).on('paste', function()
{/*works*/}
```

but I can't get the two working together in a single function! e.g.

```
jQuery(input).on('keypress, paste', function()
{/*just doesn't work WTF? */}
```

(FWIW), here's what I have... [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wallabykid/88j9n/3/)

```
// Add placeholder browser support as needed.
jQuery(function()
{   if(!ph_support()) alt_placeholder();
});
function alt_placeholder()
{   jQuery('input[placeholder]').each(function()
    {   //Assign to those input elements that have 'placeholder' attribute
        var input = jQuery(this);
        jQuery(input).val(input.attr('placeholder')).addClass('hasPlaceholder');
        jQuery(input).on('paste', function()
        {   input.removeClass('hasPlaceholder');
            if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder'))
                input.val('');
        });
        jQuery(input).on('keypress', function()
        {   input.removeClass('hasPlaceholder');
            if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder'))
                input.val('');
        });
        jQuery(input).blur(function()
        {   if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder'))
                input.val(input.attr('placeholder')).addClass('hasPlaceholder');
        });
    });
}
function ph_support()
{   var test = document.createElement('input');
    if('placeholder' in test) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045692/jquery-onpaste-for-the-first-time-doesnt-grab-or-pass-the-value

Comment: That post might be somewhat related, but it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Remove the comma**

```
jQuery(input).on('keypress paste', function()
```

Comment: Geesh! Sometimes you just can't see the trees for the forest!
Duhhh... Thanks!